# Connecting a SQLite database to a C# Windows Phone 8 Application in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, database-connection

I am making a C# Windows Phone 8 application in Visual Studio 2012. I want to read data from a SQLite database. I tried import using "Finisar.SQLite;" by referring to the relevent dll. But it gives me following error. But it works fine in Desktop applications.

[image: the error I got]

What is the correct procedure of connecting a SQLite database to a Windos Phone Application ?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully written a couple Windows Phone apps using SQLite with the [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) library. Or, this [blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/12/using-the-sqlite-database-engine-with-windows-phone-8-apps.aspx) is a basic tutorial for using the SQLite for Windows Phone Nuget package.

Comment: What is the efficient way ? My app relies on speed of getting data from the database